# basic sql query -- where prefix =

Tags: sql

So lets say I had a table of cars with attributes make and model.

Now I want to query for all cars whose model starts with the letters 'Ex'

so it would be some thing like

```
SELECT model FROM cars WHERE model = 'Ex';
```

But I guess that only returns cars whose entire model name is Ex, not whose model starts with Ex. What is the query I need here?

I can't find any good resources that list basic queries such as this. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [LIKE (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) operator.

For example:

```
SELECT model FROM cars WHERE model like 'Ex%';
```

Comment: so then if I wanted to query for models that ended in the letters er I would do something like SELECT model FROM cars WHERE model like '%er';?

Comment: @user2079802, Correct!

Comment: @user2079802 Also, if you want if model contains the string 'Ex' anywhere then you can use: model like '%Ex%'.

Answer (score 4):

You could do :

```
SELECT model FROM cars WHERE model LIKE 'Ex%';
```

Answer (score 4):

Use below query:

```
SELECT model FROM cars WHERE model LIKE 'Ex%';
```